Zeros of Legendre Polynomial and Quadrature rule
Comsider the quadrature rule $I_{n}(f)=w_{1}f(x_{1})+w_{2}f(x_{2})+\ldots +w_{n}f(x_{n})$ for approximating $I(f)=\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx$
a)Suppose $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots x_{n}$ are the zeros of the Legendre polynomial of degree $n$ denoted as $Q_{n}(x)$ and $w_{k}=\int_{-1}^{1}\prod_{j \neq k}^{n}\frac{x-x_{j}}{x_{k}-x_{j}}dx$ for $k=1,2,\ldots n$. Prove the degree of precision of $I_{n}(f)$ is at least $2n-1$.
b)Derive the quadrature formula $I_{n}(f)$ on a general interval $[a,b]$ using the quadrature formula on $[-1,1]$ constructed in part(a)
c)Prove for any choices of distinct real numbers $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots x_{n}\in [a,b]$ and real numbers $w_{1},w_{2},\ldots w_{n}$, the degree of precision of $I_{n}(f)$ is at most $2n-1$.
My attempt is:
Let $Q_{n}(x)$ be the n th degree Legendre polynomial, and assume that $p$ is a polynomial with degree less than or equal to $2n-1$. Then $p(x)=Q_{n}(x)k(x)+r(x)$ where $deg(r(x))<n$. Now $\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}Q_{n}(x)k(x)dx+\int_{-1}^{1}r(x)dx$. Now since $deg (k(x))\leq n-1$, $k(x)$ can be written as a linear combination of $Q_{1},Q_{2},\ldots Q_{n-1}$.If $k(x)=c_{1}Q_{1}+c_{2}Q_{2},\ldots c_{n-1}Q_{n-1}$. Then $\int_{-1}^{1}Q_{n}(x)k(x)dx=0$ by using orthogonality of Legendre polynomials $Q_{1},Q_{2},\ldots ,Q_{n}$ with respect to the inner product $<p,q>=\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx$. Hence $\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}r(x)dx$. But now use $deg(r(x))\leq n-1$ Therefore by the interpolation theorem $\sum_{i=1}^{n}L_{i}(x)r(x_{i})$ is the unique polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n-1$ that interpolates $r$ at $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots x_{n}$ therefore $r(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}L_{i}(x)r(x_{i})$. Now use $x_{i}$ are the roots of $Q_{n}(x)$. Hence $\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}r(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}L_{i}(x)r(x_{i})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}r(x_{i})$ Now use $p(x_{i})=Q_{n}(x_{i})k(x_{i})+r(x_{i})$ and $Q_{n}(x_{i})=0$ using $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots x_{n}$ are roots of $Q_{n}(x)$. Hence $p(x_{i})=r(x_{i})$ for all $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}$ so we obtained $\int_{-1}^{1}p(x)dx=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}p(x_{i})$.Hence degree of precision of $I_{n}(f)$ is at least $2n-1$. For the second part use $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}f(\frac{b-a}{2}t+\frac{b+a}{2})\frac{b-a}{2}dt$ and say $g(t)=f(\frac{b-a}{2}t+\frac{b+a}{2})\frac{b-a}{2}$. This implies the formula should be $\frac{b-a}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}f(\frac{b-a}{2}x_{i}+\frac{b+a}{2})]$. For the third part consider the n th degree polynomial with roots $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots x_{n}$ and say it $\psi_{n}$. Then $\int_{a}^{b}\psi_{n}^{2}(x)dx \geq 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_{i}\psi_{n}^{2}(x_{i})=0$ However since $\psi_{n}^{2}(x)$ is a positive function  $\int_{a}^{b}\psi_{n}^{2}(x)dx \neq 0$. Hence degree of precision can not be $2n$.
My question is is there any flow in my arguments can my solution be written better or is everything okay with the order and correctness of those arguments I did to solve this question?
Regards

The solution looks good to me.
